# How to escape a string for use in XML/HTML document in Scala?

Tags: html, xml, scala, escaping

Specifically, what's the easiest and most idiomatic way to replace *special* XML characters in a string. E.g., what's the easiest and most idiomatic way to convert `<Jack & Jill>` to `&lt;Jack &amp; Jill&gt;`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Turns out there is an easy way to do this (despite a quick web-search not revealing an obvious solution): just use method `xml.Utility.escape`.

Comment: xml.Utility.escape does not escape e.g. « &laquo; see my answer proposal

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to escape the `@` sign in a scala.html file, for instance, using Scala/Play, do `@@`.

And give the person who provided this answer here [How to print @ symbol in HTML with play framework (scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157571/how-to-print-symbol-in-html-with-play-framework-scala) an upvote.

I came across this page while looking for the above answer, so I just wanted to duplicate it here since other people may end up here as well.

Answer (score 1):

I propose using the function `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4`, added into `build.sbt` by `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-text" % "1.9"`

( `xml.Utility.escape` does *not* escape e.g. `«` `&laquo;` )

Comment: This is helpful; I've noticed `xml.Utility.escape` does not support anything beyond the default XML entities.

Answer (score 0):

Using scala-xml you can create a `scala.xml.Text` node and print content using `toString`:

```
println(scala.xml.Text("<Jack & Jill>").toString)
```

This will show:

```
&lt;Jack &amp; Jill&gt;
```