# How to print @ symbol in HTML with play framework (scala)

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-2.10, playframework-2.2, scala-template

I am new to Scala and play 2.1 and I come from a PHP background. I am not able to print the `@` symbol in HTML. I am getting the following error:

> not found: value Hotmail

Here is my code:

```
myname<label>@Hotmail.com</label>
```

Please let me know how I can print the `@`symbol.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Double it:

```
myname<label>@@Hotmail.com</label>
```

It's called escape syntax. Other rules for play template framework can be found [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write HTML Entity code &#64 for printing @ symbol in your view file.